# Changing action of form within div by div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i have to change the action of a form within a div without using the form id by jquery, javascript, instead i have to use the div id.
and i tired this code but it does not worked:

```
$("#popup form:action").attr('value','address here');
```

The below is the div with form

```
<div id="popup">
    <form name="frm_categories" id="frm_categories" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="attributes" id="new_attribute">
        //codes
    </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

can any body help me....

Comment: Have you tried `$("#popup form").attr('action','address here');`?

Comment: Thanks pal...that was my mistake for that thing i was bothered an hour....

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$('#popup form').attr('action', 'address');
```